# Javascript: Can data be passed bi-directionally through an iframe?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom, web-applications, iframe

For anyone with specific knowledge of it, this all relates to the WordPress "Theme Customizer", though that's not necessary to answer this.

Basically, I have a page (in PHP) which contains a left-side "pane" of settings which apply to the contents of an iframe, which is the right portion of the screen.

Conceptually, I'm looking to use [jQuery draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) to make the CSS `background-position` of the main background image adjustable via the draggable function.  I need to apply `draggable()` on the `customize.php` page, enqueue the script there, and then manipulate the DOM inside the iframe.  It needs to be done at the container/parent level because there is a setting at that level which will update the X and Y coordinates and save them in the settings stored there.

I think what I need might be impossible, but I'm wondering if it's possible with javascript to do **both** of the following:

1. Get the content of the iframe
2. Manipulate the DOM **inside the iframe**, adjust the background image via `draggable()` and store `background-position` coordinates as a data-attribute and then save them to the appropriate setting input field.

In my experience, manipulating the DOM inside an iframe from the "parent" / container level is difficult and I'm wondering if there's something I don't know, it's definitely impossible, or there is some workaround? (Note that the originating domain is the same, so there would not be any cross-domain iframe issues)

Comment: if the domain of iframe and parent matches you can communicate between both. thats how editors like TinyMCE and CKEditor work. js objects can be passed between both but with dom objects you need to take care because of memory leaks and other problems. if you use libraries like jQuery it would also work, but only if the context is the right document.

Comment: an additional note. you cant get draggable working out of the box from document to iframe. it is possible, but it requires some event passing from iframe to document and the other way round, and some additional customization. but generally it is possible. i got something like this working. but because it was just a test i don't know if i still have it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  If you find it and feel like sharing code I'll happily accept it as an answer for the benefit of others looking do to the same.

Comment: But either way, it sounds possible and that's primarily what I was asking.

Comment: i reread your question, and think i misunderstood it. you only want to make a background image movable, but not to drag an element from the parent to the iframe? i just ask because then you would not need to do much to get it work.

Comment: That's correct.  I don't need to drag the image to the parent, I need to move in the iframe and have the new coordinates update an input field in the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reduced code of my test implementation for parent iframe communication. i added some samples how it could be used. But i have to note that it is out of my labs section, and i currently don't have had the time to check if it is fully cross browser compatible. but if it is not there will only be some minor change that are have to be done. (**EDIT** tested in current chrome, ff and IE 6-9)

I hope this will help you with you problem. But again i cannot guarantee right now that it will work perfectly (but i'm pretty sure).

**code of the parent**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    (function($, window, undefined) {

        var iframe;

        // the connector object the will be passed to the iframe and will be used as "API"
        var parentConnector = {
            _window   : window, // a reference to the parents window (not really necessary but nice to have)
            $ : $,              // a reference to the parents jQuery that can be accessed from the iframe (use with caution)

            // here you will define you "API" for the parent (the functions you want to call from the iframe )
            setElementValue : function(selector, value ) {
                $(selector).val(value);
            }

        }

        // this function is called by the iframe to register the iframe in the parent
        window.registerIFrame = function( iframeHelper ) {
            //if you have multible iframe in the parent you could change the code here to store them in e.g. an arrray or with a key in an object
            iframe = iframeHelper;

            // register the parent in the iframe
            iframe.registerParent(parentConnector);
        }



        $(document).on("click",".slideUp",function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            /*
            call a function on the helper object, this is the savest way for the commincation because
            there is it minimizes the risk to mix the differnt context
            */
            iframe.slideUp();

            /*
            This way would work at least in chrome, with the current version with jquery, but it relays the jQuery implementation
            that the correct document is used.
            */
            iframe.$(".info-from-parent").val("slideUp");

            /*
            One thing you should NEVER do is the following:

            iframe.$(".info-from-parent").append( $("<div></div>") );

            The reason you should not do this is because this mixes DOMElements of different context.
            This will result in unexpected crashes/bahaviors in some browsers (but could work in others, or at least it will look like it would work)
            */

        });


        // same as the slide down, it is just there to have some interaction sample
        $(document).on("click",".slideDown",function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            iframe.slideDown();
            iframe.$(".info-from-parent").val("slideDown");
        });


    })(jQuery, window);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="info-from-iframe"><br>
    <a href="#" class="slideUp">slideUp</a> <a href="#" class="slideDown">slideDown</a><br>
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**code of the iframe**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>iframe</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>

    (function($,window,undefined) {

        //the connector object the will be passed to the parent and will be used as "API"
        var iframeConnector = {

            _window : window,     // a reference to the iframes window (not really necessary but nice to have)
            _parent : undefined,
            $ : $,                // a reference to the iframes jQuery that can be accessed from the parent (use with caution)

            // this function is called by the parent to register the parent in the iframe
            registerParent : function( parent ) {
                this._parent = parent;
            },

            /* here you will define you "API" for the iframe (the functions you want to call from the parent )*/
            slideUp : function() {
                $(".test").slideUp();
            },

            slideDown : function() {

                $(".test").slideDown();
            },

            setElementValue : function(selector, value ) {
                $(selector).val(value);
            }

        };

        // register the iframe in the parent
        window.parent.registerIFrame(iframeConnector); 

        $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
            //use the parents "API" to call a function in the parent
            iframeConnector._parent.setElementValue(".info-from-iframe", event.clientX+", "+event.clientY);
        });

    })(jQuery,window);


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="info-from-parent"><br>
    <div class="test">
        iframe
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```