# How to assign text to label which is in iFrame using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

Iam having two pages Parent.aspx and Child.aspx

Iam using IFrame to show my Child.aspx from parent like this

```
  <div id="Omit" class="Omit" style="display:none">
      <iframe src="Omission.aspx" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>
    </div>
```

In my Omission.aspx iam having a label in which i get values from Parent to show in that label

```
  <div class="Right">

        <p>
            <strong style="color: #000;">Omit</strong>
            <asp:Label ID="lblOne" runat="server" CssClass="lblOne" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:Label>

        </p>
    </div>
```

Here when i assign Text to label iam not getting

```
   var Text = $(".ddlName option:selected").text(); //Dropdwon of Parent.aspx
```

i need this value to be assigned to Label which is in Iframe 
i have tried these ways as

```
  $(".lblOne").text($(".ddlService option:selected").text())
  $(".lblOne").text(Text);
  $('#<%= lblOne.ClientID %>').html(Text)
  $('#<%= lblOne.ClientID %>').text(Text)
```

Iam unable to bing Text to that Label..,
Can anyone please help me out from this small situation of assigning, 
Thanks in Advace

Comment: look at this answer of me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884994/javascript-can-data-be-passed-bi-directionally-through-an-iframe/15928562#15928562  it is little bit more then you need, but probably you need more later.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: @t.niese But here iam not assigning iframe by Jquery i just want to assign Text to a label which is the other page of iframe

Comment: @Pink look at the link of  VimalStan that's the easiest way. the answer i linked to is for creating a clean interface between parent and iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get the iFrame jQuery Object
var $MyFrame = $("#iframeid");

// You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
// So, that the click events work properly
$MyFrame.load(function () {
    var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');

    // Find the label 
    var $label = frameBody.find('.lblOne');

    // Set the label text
    $label.html(Text);
});
```