# How to set jQuery data() on an iFrame body tag and retrieve it from inside the iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parameters, jquery-data

I'm stuck trying to set `data()` on an iFrame I create.

This is what I'm doing:

```
  // options > my configuration object
  // options.src = eg "path/foo.html"
  // options.id = uuid
  // options.parent = $(elem)
  // options.param = JSON object 

  newHTML = document.createElement("iframe");
  newHTML.setAttribute("src", options.src);
  newHTML.setAttribute("frameborder", 0);
  newHTML.setAttribute("seamless", "seamless");
  newHTML.setAttribute("data-id", options.id);

  newParentElement = options.parent.parent()[0];
  options.parent.replaceWith( newHTML ); 

  // select 
  newRootElement = newParentElement.querySelectorAll(
    '[data-id="'+options.id+'"]'
  );

  // add configuration 
  $( newRootElement[0] ).load(function () {
    var newElement = $(this);
    if (options.param) {
      newElement.contents().find("body").attr("foo","bar").data("config", options.param);
    }
  });
```

When I look at my iframe and it's body tag, the `attr("foo")` is correctly set and I can also console it like so:

```
  console.log(newElement.contents().find("body").attr("foo"));
```

but when I try to console the `config` using either `data()` or `data("config")`, like so:

```
  console.log(newElement.contents().find("body").data("config"));
```

it always returns `undefined`

**Question**:
Why is it not possible to set a jQuery `data()` on an iFrame? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: is options.param a valid string? and why arent you using jQuery syntax for all your script? would be much easier :)

Comment: jQuery does not store the data with the element itself. It just stores  an `id` with the element. The data itself is stored in `jQuery.cache`.  If you set data from outside the iframe with the `jQuery` object of the parent then the data that is set _lives_ in the parent and is not retrievable using `.data` with the `jQuery` object of the iframe. Thats because the two jQuery objects don't share their `.cache` object.

Comment: @t.niese: ah. thanks. Can you make it an answer, so I can check?

Comment: I have tested your code in FF, Safari and Chrome and it works. Here is a fiddle http://jsbin.com/atezot/3/edit. Make sure you don't retrieve data before you set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not store the data with the element itself but in `jQuery.cache`.

In jQuery code you have this part:

```
jQuery.expando: "jQuery" + ( core_version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" )
```

As you can see for each jQuery load a unique expando is created.

The expando is used as property to store an identifier with the DOM element.

When you store data with `.data(key,value)` in an element jQuery does the following steps:

1. check if there is an `id` stored with the element in `element[jQuery.expando]` if not it creates an unique `id`.
2. check if there is an entry with `jQuery.cache[id]`  if not create an empty object for storing the data for the element there.

So if you call `.data(key,value)` the data is stored in the window the jQuery instance you use is defined in.

If you have a jQuery object in the `parent` and one in the `iframe` these have two different `expandos` because of the random number. And if you call `.data()` from the parents jQuery object on an element of the iframe, the `expando` of the parent is used and the data is stored within the parent. If you then use the iframes jQuery and then call `.data`on the same element as before the iframe's jQuery would not find any data because it has on the one hand a different `expando` and on the other hand the data is stored in the parent window.

So if you want to set data in the iframe you should use the iframes jQuery object.
`$('iframe')[0].contentWindow.jQuery("body").data( ... )` to set the data, then it is possible to retrive that data from inside of the iframe again, because then you use the same jQuery object for setting and reading the data.

**EDIT**
One additional and important note. Because the data is stored with the used jQuery instance, you should not use jQuery to store data in another context. JQuery has a cleanup methode that is called when you remove elements with jQuery which removes event listeners and removes the data from `jQuery.cache`. But if you use jQuery to store data for an element that is in another context this cleanup method will fail ( e.g. if you load another page in the iframe). So the data then will only be freed if you reload the parent.

Comment: @frequent probably my answer to this question will also useful for you: [Javascript: Can data be passed bi-directionally through an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884994/javascript-can-data-be-passed-bi-directionally-through-an-iframe/)

Comment: cool. I will be doing something like this once I have the iframes working :-) thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your jQuery selector is looking up in the relevant scope by providing second parameter to `$(selector, scope)`.

```
$(function() {
    var scope = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document; // <iframe>
    $('body', scope).data('id', 'some id');            // set data on body of iframe 
    console.log($('body', scope).data('id'));          // ==> 'some id'
});
```

Here is a fiddle where I successfully set data to iframe's body and then retrieve it: http://jsbin.com/ecenij/1/edit

Comment: cool. `scope` is handy. Trying above and whether it could be timing issues.

Comment: @Vadim you should not set data or attach event listeners this way because then the cleanup method of jquery will fail if you load another page in the iframe (then data that was set with `.data` in the iframe will be in memory until the parent window is reloaded.)