# Move elements to iframe's parent with data and events

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

this is the situation.
I have a complex UI inside an iframe in which a user can perform several actions before submitting. During the process, the user can switch to another page (in the iframe) and come back. That means 2 postbacks inside the iframe.

Obviously, I don't want the user to lose everything but since all the actions have been done on the client-side, I can't reload the previous state from the server.

So now, I'm trying to move the first page content to the iframe parent and put it back in place when we come back. I'm half way there since the elements show back in the page but they lose their data attributes and event handlers.

I'm using this to move the content on the parent :

```
$("#resp").clone(true).attr("id", "refillResp").appendTo(window.top.$("#global"));
```

And this to put it back :

```
window.top.$("#global").find("#refillResp").clone(true).attr("id", "resp").appendTo($("#tdResp"));
```

Is there anyone who knows a way to do this ?
PS: I've tested how the content react when simply moved on the parent and data and events are already gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more a comment, but it does not fit in there.

Moving DOM element around different documents around is alway a little bit risky. Because it could lead to unexpected behavior (memory leaks, elements that behave strange). In current browsers it most of the time works, but i would not recommend it.

If you use jQuery you have another problem. jQuery has a cache for storing informations about `data` and `event` that are assigned to an Object, this cache is stored with the documents window. For further details please read this answer, to another question:

[How to set jQuery data() on an iFrame body tag and retrieve it from inside the iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689280/how-to-set-jquery-data-on-an-iframe-body-tag-and-retrieve-it-from-inside-the-i/16690904#16690904)

So if you move element with jQuery between different document, you will currently on the one hand loose these informations, on the other hand it could result in memory leaks.

With events it is even more complicate. e.g. if you have delegated events it could be become completely messy.

If you need to exchange data between iframe and parent you should think of some other logic.

I also mention this in a comment to the other answer of me, where i referred to this post: 
[How to set jQuery data() on an iFrame body tag and retrieve it from inside the iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884994/javascript-can-data-be-passed-bi-directionally-through-an-iframe/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll this problem at that. I already change that screen mechanisms to avoid the case mentioned above. I had no clue about the "secrets" behind data and events and concluded after a bit of learning that it was a very bad idea.

Comment: @Synryu that's the advantage about SO, i learn so many new things or how to do it a _better way_ by just reading. I would not say using `iframe` is a bad idea. There are use cases where they perfectly fit the requirements if you know the pitfall, especially in conjunction with libraries like `jQuery`.